# Is it possible to change any value dynamically in a dockerized web application

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot application with logback.I am containerizing this application in docker.As once image is created its immutable is it possible to change log level dynamically one container and application is started.
In the application I am exposing log back properties via servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can go inside your running Dockerized container.
I am assuming you are using Ubuntu/Centos as base image.

The docker exec command is probably what you are looking for, this will let you run arbitrary commands inside an existing container.

```
docker exec -it <containerid> bash
```

where  is ID of your container or name of the running container.

If you are using Docker for development purpose, then I'll suggest you to use UI for your Docker system.
You can install Docker UI using - [portainer.io](http://portainer.io)
With this, you can easily check logs, go inside container... etc